# What is the 'when keyword' used for in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, keyword

What is the `when` keyword used for in T-SQL?

```
when
```

**NOTE:** I tried searching this on the web (e.g. 'Googling')... however due to the ubiquitous nature of the word 'when', I wasn't able to find a good explanation.

Furthermore, a list of SQL keywords did not include 'when' so either the list was not exhaustive or it is unique to T-SQL (or perhaps it was added in some 'newer' version of T-SQL / SSMS).  Link to this particular SQL keyword site:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_keywords.asp

Comment: Refer to the documentation for the [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's used in conjunction with the CASE keyword, which is like a switch, or 'if' statement essentially... for example:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN [Column] = 1 THEN 'Column is 1'
         WHEN [Column] = 2 THEN 'Column is 2'
         ELSE 'Column is not 1 or 2'
         END AS [Description]
```

Answer (score 2):

`WHEN` is also part of [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement:

> Runs insert, update, or delete operations on a target table from the results of a join with a source table
>
> ```
> MERGE
>     [ INTO ] <target_table> [ WITH ( <merge_hint> ) ] [ [ AS ] table_alias ]  
>     USING <table_source>
>     ON <merge_search_condition>  
>     [ WHEN MATCHED [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]  
>         THEN <merge_matched> ] [ ...n ]  
>     [ WHEN NOT MATCHED [ BY TARGET ] [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]  
>         THEN <merge_not_matched> ]  
>     [ WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]  
>         THEN <merge_matched> ] [ ...n ]  
> ;
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this could be very useful for someone